# WooCommerce - Multiple cart dicounts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I want a cart discount based on the total
5% over $600 order and 10% over $1000?
I can get it to work for the over $600 but not the over $1000. I get an error on line 15.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_matched_coupons' );

function apply_matched_coupons() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $coupon_code = 'over600'; // your coupon code here
    $coupon_codeb = 'over1000'; // your coupon code here

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 600 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
        $woocommerce->show_messages();
    }
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total >= 1000 ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_codeb );
        $woocommerce->show_messages();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @dhcrain!  Please include the full text of the error message you are seeing.

Comment: What's the error? And how are we supposed to know where line 15 is?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing it a completely different way

```
function nh_custom_coupon_filter() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $excluded_amount = $discount_percent = 0;
  $working_total   = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total;
  $excluded_categories = array(
    217, # Training
    223, # Starter Kits
  );

  # Only apply manual discount if no coupons are applied
  if (!$woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons) {

    # Find any items in cart that belong to the restricted categories
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $item) {
      $product_categories = get_the_terms($item['product_id'], 'product_cat');
      if (empty($product_categories) || is_wp_error($product_categories) || !$product_categories) {
        if (is_wp_error($product_categories)) {
          wp_die($product_categories->get_error_message());
        }
        else {
          $product_categories = new WP_Error('no_product_categories', "The product \"".$item->post_title."\" doesn't have any categories attached, thus no discounts can be calculated.", "Fatal Error");
          wp_die($product_categories);
        }
      }
      foreach ($excluded_categories as $excluded_category) {
        foreach ($product_categories as $category) {
          if ($excluded_category == $category->term_id) {
            $excluded_amount += $item['line_subtotal']; # Increase our exclusion amount
            $working_total -= $item['line_subtotal'];   # Decrease our discountable amount
          }
        }
      }
    }

    # Logic to determine WHICH discount to apply based on subtotal
    if ($working_total >= 600 && $working_total < 1000) {
      $discount_percent = 5;
    }
    elseif ($working_total >= 1000) {
      $discount_percent = 10;
    }
    else {
      $discount_percent = 0;
    }

    # Make sure cart total is eligible for discount
    if ($discount_percent > 0) {
      $discount_amount  = ( ( ($discount_percent/100) * $working_total ) * -1 );
      $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Bulk Discount', $discount_amount);
    }
  }
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'nh_custom_coupon_filter');
```